# Unable to profile tests in Visual Studio 2013 when assembly path contains spaces

Tags: visual-studio-2013, profiling

Whenever I try to profile a test in Visual Studio 2013, by Right-Clicking on the test in Test Explorer, and selecting the "Profile Test" option, the test successfully executes (and passes), but the performance analysis fails with the following messages.

```
File contains no data buffers
File contains no data buffers
Analysis failed
```

I am using Windows 7 64.

I can successfully profile the application itself (both Instrumentation and Sampling) with no problems.

Comment: Has anyone tried this in VS 2012? I need to instrument some sharepoint 2010 webparts and im getting the same error.

Comment: Do you have spaces in any of the assemblies that you want to instrument? Get rid of the spaces first and then try it out.

Comment: No, I do not have space in them. I think there is a problem in mismatch of strongly typed assemblies since instrumentation modifies the code thus modifying the signature.

Comment: I've had this issue in an ASP.NET MVC project, and as far as I know there are no spaces in the assemblies. However, it isn't clear what's meant by "the assemblies." Is that referring to executables produced, such as DLLs and EXEs?

Comment: @AaronCampbell, yes. In my specific case it definitely looked like the instrumentation wasn't working due to spaces in my executable. Its possible that it might be any spaces in the file paths, so I would check for that as well.

Comment: *big sigh* Yes, my Windows username has a space, which would pollute the file paths. Microsoft products are supposed to be able to handle that... Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So it turns out the problem is that if any of the assemblies that you hope to instrument over have spaces in their names, the "Profile Test" option fails to instrument them, which in turn means that no data is collected (because "Profile Test" appears to only use Instrumentation).

Obviously the workaround is to just not have assemblies with spaces in their names.

I logged a bug [on Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/814742/unable-to-profile-test-no-data-collected).

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the vstest processor architecture to x86 on Visual Studio.

It worked for me. I'm using VS2015.

Test > Test Settings > Default processor architecture > x86

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur when the assembly is signed with strong name key. I had this issue recently with VS2017